# Upload picture to server with a Nexus 4

Tags: java, android, upload

I'm new with android-programming. I am trying to get this code ready for my Nexus 4:
Hope someone can help me out so thanks in advance.

```
package com.sunil.upload;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private TextView messageText;
    private Button uploadButton, btnselectpic;
    private ImageView imageview;
    private int serverResponseCode = 0;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    private String upLoadServerUri = null;
    private String imagepath=null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
        messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);
        btnselectpic = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_selectpic);
        imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_pic);

        btnselectpic.setOnClickListener(this);
        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        upLoadServerUri = "http://192.168.0.15/UploadToServer.php";
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if(arg0==btnselectpic)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 1);
        }
        else if (arg0==uploadButton) {

             dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
             messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
             new Thread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {

                      uploadFile(imagepath);

                 }
               }).start();    
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getData().getPath();

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            messageText.setText("Uploading file path:" +imagepath);

        }
    }
         public String getPath(Uri uri) {
                String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


          String fileName = sourceFileUri;

          HttpURLConnection conn = null;
          DataOutputStream dos = null; 
          String lineEnd = "\r\n";
          String twoHyphens = "--";
          String boundary = "*****";
          int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
          byte[] buffer;
          int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
          File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

          if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

               dialog.dismiss();

               Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"+imagepath);

               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+ imagepath);
                   }
               });

               return 0;

          }
          else
          {
               try {

                     // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                   URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                   // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                   conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                   conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                   conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                   conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

                   dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                             + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                   // create a buffer of  maximum size
                   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                   buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                   // read file and write it into form...
                   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize); 

                   while (bytesRead > 0) {

                     dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                     bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                     bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                     bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                    }

                   // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                   // Responses from the server (code and message)
                   serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                   String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                   Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                           + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                   if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                      +" F:/wamp/wamp/www/uploads";
                                messageText.setText(msg);
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });               
                   }   

                   //close the streams //
                   fileInputStream.close();
                   dos.flush();
                   dos.close();

              } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                  dialog.dismiss(); 
                  ex.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });

                  Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex); 
              } catch (Exception e) {

                  dialog.dismiss(); 
                  e.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });
                  Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "  + e.getMessage(), e); 
              }
              dialog.dismiss();      
              return serverResponseCode;

           } // End else block
         }


}
```

Unfortunately I am trying to get it run without success.
What do i have to change to run it on my Nexus 4?

This is what Eclipse tells me:

08-07 22:26:35.751: E/BitmapFactory(10752): Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException

```
08-08 18:46:54.408: E/BitmapFactory(16388): Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-08 18:46:58.682: W/dalvikvm(16388): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41cc8ba8)
08-08 18:46:58.682: E/AndroidRuntime(16388): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-32596
08-08 18:46:58.682: E/AndroidRuntime(16388): Process: com.sunil.upload, PID: 16388
08-08 18:46:58.682: E/AndroidRuntime(16388): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-08 18:46:58.682: E/AndroidRuntime(16388):    at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
08-08 18:46:58.682: E/AndroidRuntime(16388):    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)
08-08 18:46:58.682: E/AndroidRuntime(16388):    at com.sunil.upload.MainActivity.uploadFile(MainActivity.java:112)
08-08 18:46:58.682: E/AndroidRuntime(16388):    at com.sunil.upload.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:69)
08-08 18:46:58.682: E/AndroidRuntime(16388):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-08 18:46:59.403: E/WindowManager(16388): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.sunil.upload.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{425df3e0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-729,192} that was originally added here
08-08 18:46:59.403: E/WindowManager(16388):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:346)
08-08 18:46:59.403: E/WindowManager(16388):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
08-08 18:46:59.403: E/WindowManager(16388):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
08-08 18:46:59.403: E/WindowManager(16388):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
08-08 18:46:59.403: E/WindowManager(16388):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
08-08 18:46:59.403: E/WindowManager(16388):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
08-08 18:46:59.403: E/WindowManager(16388):     at com.sunil.upload.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:64)
08-08 18:46:59.403: E/WindowManager(16388):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
08-08 18:46:59.403: E/WindowManager(16388):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
08-08 18:46:59.403: E/WindowManager(16388):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-08 18:46:59.403: E/WindowManager(16388):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-08 18:46:59.403: E/WindowManager(16388):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-08 18:46:59.403: E/WindowManager(16388):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
08-08 18:46:59.403: E/WindowManager(16388):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-08 18:46:59.403: E/WindowManager(16388):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-08 18:46:59.403: E/WindowManager(16388):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
08-08 18:46:59.403: E/WindowManager(16388):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
08-08 18:46:59.403: E/WindowManager(16388):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Nothing in advance. You forgot to tell what the user and code does. And which line causes the exception. It should not be to difficult to find out wich pointer is null.

Comment: Does the bitmap display?